# How do I save darkmode on all pages of my website locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, darkmode

I've seen a lot of other people with the same problem on here but all of the solutions for the problems I've seen didn't work for me so please help me with my website. For some reason my dark mode doesn't save when moving from my main html file to another. It's like saving individually for every page if I were to add a dark mode switch to the other page. For some reason the darkmode doesn't work when u run it here over snippet but it works on my computer... Well I hope u can help me. I want the dark mode to still be applied when moving from my Settings html page to my Home page.(Settings.html -> Home.html)

```js
// Get the theme toggle input
const themeToggle = document.querySelector(
  '.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]'
);


// Get the current theme from local storage
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");


// If the current local storage item can be found
if (currentTheme) {
  // Set the body data-theme attribute to match the local storage item
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", currentTheme);


  // If the current theme is dark, check the theme toggle
  if (currentTheme === "dark") {
    themeToggle.checked = true;
  }
}


// Function that will switch the theme based on the if the theme toggle is checked or not
function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
  } 
  else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
  }
}


// Add an event listener to the theme toggle, which will switch the theme
themeToggle.addEventListener("change", switchTheme, false);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");

:root {
  --bg-color: #5d5e91;
  --font-color: #222;
  --title-color: #0067e6;
  --title-background: #fff;
  --main-border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  --main-bg: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color: #111;
  --font-color: #efefef;
  --title-color: #5c50fe;
  --title-background: #222;
  --main-border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  --main-bg: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.4);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: var(--font-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);

  /* OTHER STYLING */
  margin: 0 2rem 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: "Poppins", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Symbol";
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  border: var(--main-border);
  background: var(--main-bg);

  /* OTHER STYLING */
  max-width: 65ch;
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

section {
  background: var(--title-background);

  /* OTHER SYLING */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--title-color);

  /* OTHER STYLING */
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h2 {
  color: #918a95;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

/* TOGGLE  */
.theme-switch-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.theme-switch-wrapper em {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.theme-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.theme-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #5c50fe;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider svg {
  color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s, transform 0.35s ease 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <div class="title-wrapper">
          <h1>Dark Mode</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
          <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
            <div class="slider">
      </section>
      <p>
        Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust     synopsis for high level
        overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster
        collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition.
        Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via
        workplace diversity and empowerment.
      </p>
    </main>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your console say when you log `localStorage.getItem("theme")` after setting the theme and navigating to your `Home.html`?

Comment: Did you also include js in the home.html setting the dark-theme attribute on the root element?

Comment: Works fine – maybe you have already stored a theme var during previous tests that's now interfering.

Comment: Oh wait a second it works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: In Firefox on my home page it says "Uncaught TypeError: themeToggle is null
    <anonymous> (filelocation)"

Comment: Nevermind I was able to fix that issue but it's still not working in Firefox